# Ошибка при запуске андроид эмулятора Android Studio

Tags: android

Установил я Android Studio сделал все как и должно быть, но при запуске приложения нажатие кнопки Run

Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android\sdk]!
21:37   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Вылазит вот такое, я раз 5 смотрел переменные среды в указанном пути содержится sdk потому как меня поругали за то что есть кириллица в названии пути (C:\Users\Артем\Android\sdk) переменные среды выглядят следующим образом ANDROID_HOME C:\Android\sdk  ANDROID_SDK_ROOT C:\Android\sdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value

Comment: Убедитесь что SDK действительно находится по этому пути.